# How to start a docker container from a image with a given name?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, docker-container

I am trying to run an image with a given container name.

How to achieve this?

I am running this command:

`docker run -it -d macgyvertechnology/tensorflow-gpu:basic-jupyter --name hugging-face-models-run --gpus all`

Comment: Arguments to `docker run` must be __before__ the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Docker `run` command format:

```sh
$  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

You need to update your command to

```sh
$ docker run -it -d --name hugging-face-models-run --gpus all macgyvertechnology/tensorflow-gpu:basic-jupyter
```

### Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#usage